# When running linter for Jsx-a11y it checks for configurations I haven't specified

Tags: reactjs, eslint

The following is what my eslint file looks like (only relevant config)

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "jsx-a11y"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 2, // HTML <a> element, with a valid href attribute
    "jsx-a11y/alt-text": 2, // Elements that require alternative text have meaningful information
    "jsx-a11y/no-redundant-roles": 2, // Setting an ARIA role that matches its default/implicit role is redundant
    "jsx-a11y/lang": 2, // The lang prop on the <html> element must have a valid value based on ISO country and language codes.
    "jsx-a11y/aria-props": 2, // Elements cannot use an invalid ARIA attribute | https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties
    "jsx-a11y/aria-role": [ 2, { // Elements with ARIA roles must use a valid, non-abstract ARIA role | https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions
      "ignoreNonDOM": true
    }],
    "jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions": ["error", // Non-interactive HTML elements and non-interactive ARIA require a ROLE attribute or are hidden with ARIA
      {
        "handlers": [
          "onClick",
          "onMouseDown",
          "onMouseUp",
          "onKeyPress",
          "onKeyDown",
          "onKeyUp"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For some reason, when I let the linter run it gives me error messages for configuration I haven't specified here... For example:

```
jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control
jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events
```

Am I doing something wrong? I have it installed as a dev dependency and don't want to use the recommended settings, because I don't need that many. Just the ones I specified above.

Comment: Do you have any `extends` rules in your eslint config?

Comment: Yup: `"extends": "airbnb",`@jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in a comment, your config extends `eslint-config-airbnb`.

This one [includes `jsx-a11y` itself](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb/rules/react-a11y.js), causing the linter errors you see.

If you *don't* want to see those particular errors, you will have to explicitly disable them in your own ESLint configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking back at this question:
Just add the below configuration for each rule you want to disable...
`"jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0`